# Show the content of a file in the mail body

Tags: files, mailx

I am writing a script where it shows the content of file in the body of the mail. But i am getting error while I am executing it.

```
RECIP="abc@gmail.com"
lines=`wc -l $HOME/totals`
if [ $lines == 6 ];then
mailx -s "Morning Totals" $RECIP < $HOME/totals
```

error is `0403-057 Syntax error at line 3 : 'then' is not matched`

what is error in my script.

Comment: Try `[ "$lines" -eq 6 ]`

Comment: @Costas I have tried it but still it is throwing same error. I am using `ksh`

Comment: 1. Don't use backtics ``, use `$()` for command substitution. 2. Run `wc -l < file` instead of `wc -l file` to **not** include filename into result. 3. Close `if` condition with `fi`. 4. Quote variables.

Comment: @jimmij Thanks for your valuable points, very helpful. How can I show content of two files in the body of the mail? as now I am showing only for one file.

Comment: Process substitution should do the job: `< <(cat file1 file2)`, or if you are using `zsh` then simply take advantage of multios: `<file1 <file2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `if` not closed with a `fi`:

```
if [ $lines == 6 ];then
  mailx -s "Morning Totals" $RECIP < $HOME/totals
fi
```

Comment: Sorry I have missed it. Thank you now it is working